# Wiley Latex Template Abstract goes of the page

Tags: formatting, templates, abstract, wiley-article, cls

I am using the official Latex Template for Wiley managed journals in overleaf, see the template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wiley-journal-template/nnjcnfyhzcqp). However, if I extend the abstract too much (with for example lorem ipsum, lipsum package), the abtract does not break the page but just goes off at the bottom. This happens only if you activate the twocolumn mode with: `\documentclass[num-refs,twocolumn]{wiley-article}`

[image: abstract goes off]

Also here the `wiley-article.cls` file. Is there any simple fix for that or did someone fixed that before?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% wiley-article.cls, v1.5, 2018/07/05
% Developed by Overleaf.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{wiley-article}[2018/07/05, v1.5]

%% Definitions for adding journal elements
\def\@jlogo{}
\def\@jname{}
\def\@jyear{}
\def\@jpages{}
\def\@jvolume{}
\def\@jwebsite{}

\def\@runningauthor{}
\def\@corraddress{}
\def\@corremail{}
\def\@fundinginfo{}
\def\@presentaddress{}

\def\@papertype{original article}
\def\@paperfield{}
\def\@paperdoi{}
\def\@paperreceived{}
\def\@paperrevised{}
\def\@paperaccepted{}
\def\@papereditor{}

\newif\if@numrefs
\newif\if@alpharefs
\newif\if@amsrefs
\newif\if@blindreview
\newif\if@useserif
\newif\if@wiley@lineno

%% Add options for other journals here
\DeclareOption{jabr}{%
  \def\@jlogo{jabr-logo}%
  \def\@jname{J Appl Behav Res}%
  \def\@jwebsite{wileyonlinelibrary.com/journal/jabr}%
}

%% Options for bibliography style
\DeclareOption{num-refs}{
  \@numrefstrue
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{alpha-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefstrue
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{ams-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefstrue
}

%% Option for blind review
\DeclareOption{blind}{\@blindreviewtrue}

%% v1.3: Option for serif fonts
\DeclareOption{serif}{\@useseriftrue}

%% v1.4: Option for line numbers
\DeclareOption{lineno}{\@wiley@linenotrue}

%%
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
  
%% v1.2: don't set any defaults
% \ExecuteOptions{num-refs}
\ProcessOptions\relax


\LoadClass[twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}

\if@twocolumn
  \RequirePackage[switch]{lineno}
\else
  \RequirePackage{lineno}
\fi

\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{microtype}{tracking amount list}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Reference `mdf@pagelabel}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
  \let\boldsymbol\symbf
  \if@useserif
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
    \setmathfont[Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}
  \else
%     \RequirePackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
    \setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
    \setmathfont[range={\int}]{Latin Modern Math}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato Italic}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato Bold}
  \fi
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
\else
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \if@useserif
    \RequirePackage{tgtermes}
    \RequirePackage{lato}
    \RequirePackage{stix}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[default]{lato}
    \IfFileExists{newtxsf.sty}{
      \RequirePackage[cmintegrals,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}
    }{}
  \fi
  \ifpdf
  \SetTracking[spacing={500*,166,}]{encoding={*}}{80}
  \fi
\fi


\RequirePackage
 [paperwidth=171mm,paperheight=246mm,
  left=14.3mm,textwidth=142.4mm,lines=47,
  headsep=\baselineskip,headheight=16\p@,
  footskip=23\p@,columnsep=2em]
{geometry}

\RequirePackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\@fnsymbol}{5}

\newcounter{authorfn}
\setcounter{authorfn}{1}
\newcommand{\authfn}[1]{%
  \fnsymbolmult{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\presentadd}[2][]{
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress\else\appto{\@presentaddress}{\\}{}{}\fi
  \appto{\@presentaddress}{%
  \ifx\empty#1\else\textsuperscript{#1}\fi
  #2%
  }{}{}
}


%% These will be set by the \journal{} command
\newcommand{\jlogo}[1]{\def\@jlogo{#1}}
\newcommand{\jname}[1]{\def\@jname{#1}}
\newcommand{\jyear}[1]{\def\@jyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\jvolume}[1]{\def\@jvolume{#1}}
\newcommand{\jpages}[1]{\def\@jpages{#1}}
\newcommand{\jwebsite}[1]{\def\@jwebsite{#1}}


\newcommand{\runningauthor}[1]{\def\@runningauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\corraddress}[1]{\def\@corraddress{#1}}
\newcommand{\corremail}[1]{\def\@corremail{#1}}

\newcommand{\fundinginfo}[1]{\def\@fundinginfo{#1}}

\newcommand{\paperdoi}[1]{\def\@paperdoi{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperreceived}[1]{\def\@paperreceived{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperrevised}[1]{\def\@paperrevised{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperaccepted}[1]{\def\@paperaccepted{#1}}
\newcommand{\papereditor}[1]{\def\@papereditor{#1}}
\newcommand{\papertype}[1]{\def\@papertype{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperfield}[1]{\def\@paperfield{#1}}

% normal font is 8pt/13pt
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[13\p@]{8\p@}

% sectional headings
\ifxetexorluatex
  \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][10.0]{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=#1}\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  %% Fake small caps
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0,Scale=0.8}\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\textls*[#1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}}
  \else
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad\allcaps{#1}}

\newcommand{\backmatter}{%
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{\allcaps{##1}}%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{ 1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{\textsc{#1}}
\else
  \ifpdf
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{\textls*{#1}}
  \else
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
  \fi
\fi
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\if@useserif
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\bfseries\selectfont}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
    {\normalsize\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
\else
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Lato Black}\color{black!75}}
      {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Lato Black}}
      {}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
      {\normalsize\fontspec{Lato Black}\color{black!75}}
      {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}

  \else
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
      {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
      {}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
      {\normalsize\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
      {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \fi
\fi

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{1em}


% Formatting of footer for first page
%% v1.4: can't use "real" footnotes anymore for twocolumn
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
%   \def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
%   \appto{\footnotelayout}{\fontsize{6\p@}{9\p@}\selectfont}
%   \let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
%   \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}}\vskip2\p@}

\def\@fpfootnotes{}
\newcommand{\blfootnote}[1]{\appto{\@fpfootnotes}{#1\par}}


%% Headers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhead[LO]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X r | r @{}}%
  \textsc{\@runningauthor} & & \thepage\\\hline
  %& %\multicolumn{1}{r}{%
    %\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}%
    %\quad%
    %\raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}} & \\
\end{tabularx}%
}}

\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}%
  \thepage & & \textsc{\@runningauthor}\\\hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{} &
%   \raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}%
%   \quad%
%   \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}\\
  \end{tabularx}%
}}

%% First page header + footer
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
%   \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hdashrule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}{2\p@}\\[-2\p@]}

  \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l | X @{}}%
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}
    {\multicolumn{3}{l}{}}
    {Received: \@paperreceived &
  Revised: \@paperrevised &
  Accepted: \@paperaccepted}
  \\\hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperdoi}{}{\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{DOI: \@paperdoi}}
  \end{tabularx}}

  \fancyfoot[L]{%\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont%
%   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
%   \arrayrulecolor{black}\raggedright%
%   This is an open access article under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution License, which permits use, distribution and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited.\\[3\p@]
%   \begingroup
  \fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  r | r @{}}%
  \hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}{& & & }{%
  \textit{\@jname}~\@jyear; \@jvolume: \@jpages &
  \@jwebsite &
  \textcopyright~\@jyear\space Wiley Periodicals, Inc. &
  }
  \thepage
  \end{tabularx}%
%   \endgroup
  }
}

% For adding notes about author contributions
\newcommand{\contrib}[2][]{%
  \blfootnote{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}%
}


% Author and affiliation fonts
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{1}
\renewcommand{\Authsep}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authand}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authands}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{12\p@}{20pt}\bfseries\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont\raggedright}
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AB@affilsepx}{\\}{\\[3\p@]}{}{}

\patchcmd{\@author}{\AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]\AB@affillist}{\AB@authlist}{}{}

% % \AtBeginDocument{
%   \if@blindreview
%     \let\oldauthor\author
%     \let\oldaffil\affil
%     \renewcommand{\author}[2][]{\oldauthor{Author}}
%     \renewcommand{\affil}[2][]{\oldaffil{An affiliation}}
% % %     \def\AB@authors{Anonymous Authors}
% %     \def\AB@affillist{Anonymous Affiliations}
%   \fi
% % }

% Title
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \if@blindreview
    \def\AB@authlist{\Authfont Anonymous Authors}
    \def\AB@affillist{\Affilfont Anonymous Affiliations}
    \def\@runningauthor{Authors (Anon)}
    \def\@corraddress{Anonymous correspoundence}
    \def\@corremail{anon@example.com}
    \def\@presentaddress{Anonymous present address}
    \def\@fundinginfo{Anonymous funders}
  \fi
  \vspace*{\dimexpr 27\p@-2\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\begingroup%
  \setul{3\p@}{1\p@}%
  \if@useserif
    \bfseries%
  \else
    \ifxetexorluatex\fontspec{Lato Heavy}\else\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\fi%
  \fi
  {\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{\ul{\@papertype}}}
  \ifdefempty{\@jlogo}{\rule{0pt}{2em}}{%
  \hfill%
%   \includegraphics[height=1.5em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}%
%   \quad%
  \includegraphics[height=2em]{\@jlogo}}
  \\[2\p@]%
  {\fontsize{8\p@}{15\p@}%
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\@paperfield%
  \else
    \ifpdf
    \textls*[150]{\@paperfield}%
    \else
    \@paperfield
    \fi
  \fi}
  \endgroup%
  \vskip13\p@%
  {\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}
  \vskip27\p@%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}\@author\end{minipage}%
  \vskip21\p@%
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
}

% Affiliation + other metadata
\newcommand{\wiley@affilmetadata}{%
  \AB@affillist\par%
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Correspondence}\\
  \@corraddress\\
  Email: \@corremail\par
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress
  \else%
    \vskip10pt%
    \textbf{Present address}\\
    \@presentaddress\par
  \fi%
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Funding information}\\
  \@fundinginfo\par
  \ifdefempty{\@papereditor}{}
  {\vskip10pt Editor: \@papereditor\par}
}

%% Abbreviations in the footnote
\newcommand{\abbrevs}[1]{\blfootnote{\textbf{Abbreviations:} #1\\[-3\p@]}}

%% Abstract and affiliation in the margin
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\newlength{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
\newlength{\wiley@abstractheight}
\NewEnviron{wiley@abstract}{%
  \newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
    \vskip8\p@%
    \noindent{\bfseries\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{keywords}\par}
    \noindent{\raggedright\fontsize{8\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont ##1\par}
  }%
  \strictpagecheck%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{\dimexpr 54.9mm-6.5\p@}{}%
  \setlength{\marginparsep}{-47mm}%
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{47mm}%
  %% Measure the height of the affil metadata in the sidebar
  \settototalheight{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\wiley@affilmetadata}}%
  \newsavebox{\wiley@abstractbox}%
  %% Save the abstract text in a box
  \savebox{\wiley@abstractbox}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
      topline=false,bottomline=false,
      leftline=true,rightline=false,
      backgroundcolor=black!10,
      middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
      outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]
      \BODY
    \end{mdframed}}%
  }%
  \settototalheight{\wiley@abstractheight}{\usebox{\wiley@abstractbox}}%
  \marginnote{\wiley@affilmetadata}%
  \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
  topline=false,bottomline=false,
  leftline=true,rightline=false,
  backgroundcolor=black!10,
  middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
  outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]%
  %% v1.5: number the abstract lines as well
  \if@wiley@lineno
    \internallinenumbers\rightlinenumbers\resetlinenumber%
  \fi%
  \BODY%
  \end{mdframed}%
  %% If the affildata is taller than the abstract, add vskip
  \ifdimgreater
    {\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
    {\wiley@abstractheight}
    {\vskip\dimexpr\wiley@affilmetadataheight-\wiley@abstractheight+1.5\baselineskip\relax}
    {\vskip1.5\baselineskip}
}[\end{adjustwidth*}]%

\renewcommand{\abstract}{\wiley@abstract}
\renewcommand{\endabstract}{\endwiley@abstract}

\newcommand{\thefpfootnotes}{%
  \noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}}\\
  {\fontsize{6\p@}{9\p@}\selectfont
  \@fpfootnotes}
}

%% v1.4: Add two-column mode 
\NewEnviron{frontmatter}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \let\oldclearpage\clearpage
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \ifdefvoid{\@fpfootnotes}{}{%
      \begin{figure*}[b!]
      \thefpfootnotes
      \end{figure*}
    }  
    \twocolumn[\@twocolumnfalse\setlength\parindent{2em}\BODY]
    \let\clearpage\oldclearpage
  \else
    \BODY
  \fi%
}

% v1.4: Add line numbers too
\if@wiley@lineno
  \AfterEndEnvironment{frontmatter}{\linenumbers}
  \if@twocolumn\else
    \AfterEndEnvironment{abstract}{\linenumbers}  
  \fi
\fi

\if@twocolumn\else
  \appto{\maketitle}{%
    \ifdefvoid{\@fpfootnotes}{}{%
      \begin{figure*}[b!]
      \thefpfootnotes
      \end{figure*}
    }  
  }
\fi

% quotes and epigraphs
\RequirePackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=\baselineskip,indentfirst=false,font={itshape,RaggedRight,normalsize},leftmargin=26\p@,rightmargin=26\p@}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\renewenvironment{quotation}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{epigraph}[1]
{\begin{quoting}\def\@quotesource{#1}}
{\par\hfill\@quotesource\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{pullquote}
{\begin{quoting}[vskip=\dimexpr 39\p@-23\p@\relax,leftmargin=12\p@,rightmargin=12\p@,font+={raggedright},begintext={\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\selectfont\color{black!50}}]}
{\end{quoting}}

% Enum/itemized
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,font=\bfseries,leftmargin=*,align=left}
\setlist[1]{topsep=\baselineskip,leftmargin=\parindent,labelsep=*,labelwidth=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*.},}

% Space above/below equations
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
}

% All the popular math environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
      \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
      \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
      \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

% Captions
\RequirePackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{captionfont}{\fontsize{8\p@}{11\p@}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{boxcaption}{\fontsize{9\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont}
\ifxetexorluatex
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontspec{Lato Black}}
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
\else
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontseries{eb}}
  \ifpdf
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\textls[150]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
  \else
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}
  \fi
\fi
\if@useserif
  \captionsetup*{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=captionfont,labelformat=allcaps,labelfont={bf},labelsep=quad}
\else
  \captionsetup*{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=captionfont,labelformat=allcaps,labelfont={heavy},labelsep=quad}
\fi
\captionsetup*[table]{skip=0.5ex}

% Tables
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont%
  \rowcolors*{3}{black!10}{}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black!20}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1\p@}%
}

\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\leftmargin=0pt}
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries #1\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{2em}}}

%% Boxes!
\RequirePackage{stfloats}
\RequirePackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=bt,name=box]{featurebox}
\captionsetup*[featurebox]{skip=1em,labelformat={default},font={heavy,boxcaption},labelfont={sc,color=black!75}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{featurebox}{%
  \setlist*{topsep=0pt}%
}
\apptocmd{\featurebox}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=5\p@,linecolor=black!20,
  innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
  innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@]
}{}{}
\pretocmd{\endfeaturebox}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}


% Skips for floats
\setlength{\floatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}

% The endnotes
\RequirePackage{enotez}
\newlist{enotezlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enotezlist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*,labelsep=0.25em,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0.5\baselineskip}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}
{list-type=enotezlist}
\setenotez{list-name={endnotes},list-style=itemize}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}{
  format=\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont,
  number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}

% References
\if@numrefs
  \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{vancouver-authoryear}
\fi
\if@alpharefs
    \RequirePackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{rss}
\fi
\if@amsrefs
  \RequirePackage{amsrefs}
  \let\citep\cite
  \let\citet\ocite
  \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{
    \setlength{\bibhang}{1.5em}
    \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{references}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{references}
  }{}

  \@ifpackageloaded{amsrefs}{
    \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{references}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{references}
  }{}
}

% Author biography
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\newenvironment{biography}[2][]
{\begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=0.5\p@,skipabove=1.5\baselineskip,%nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=6\p@,innerrightmargin=6\p@,
    innertopmargin=6\p@,innerbottommargin=6\p@]
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}
  {\lettrine[image,lines=5,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}}%
  {\bfseries\scshape #2}}
{\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\otherinfo}[2][]{%
  \backmatter%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{suppinfo}
  {\section{Supporting Information}
  Additional Supporting Information may be found online in the supporting information for this article.}
  {}

  \begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=1\p@,linecolor=black!40,nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
    innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@,
    skipabove=\baselineskip]
  \textbf{How to cite this article:} #2
  \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{graphicalabstract}[1]{%
  \backmatter
  \section{graphical abstract}
  \lettrine[image,lines=10,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}%
}{}

% Here we go!
\normalsize
\pagestyle{fancy}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \robustify{\ref}
  \robustify{\cite}
  \ifdef{\citep}{\robustify{\citep}}{}
  \ifdef{\citet}{\robustify{\citet}}{}
}
```

Also here just the beginning of my latex file with the abstract:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1-6]

% Please include a maximum of seven keywords
\keywords{Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, ...}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can't really "fix" publisher styles, the whole point is that they remove author choice and enforce a house style. Presumably they want abstracts that fit in that space, possibly so that publications of extracted abstracts are not too long)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I dont think so, if you read papers of this journal "African Journal of Ecology" using this template, abstracts (and in this section there is a resume included) are longer than a page.

Comment: Using the template on Overleaf and your code for the abstract, I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you activate the twocolumn layout? @SimonDispa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others wondering, I solved it by just keeping the one-column layout and manually adding a `\begin{multicols}{2}` about the introduction section using the package `multicols`.

Much simpler than I thought

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).